# How to click one of button to display an image in TableViewCell for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This function is show each status in UITableViewCell. The status of image is green (Default). When I click one of button, it will display image of red.

click button function is

```
func get(_ sender: UIButton){}
```

This is display red image

```
let imageName = "red.png"
 let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
 index.red.image = image
```

It does not work! how to solve? The code is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",for:indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.gets.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.gets.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.get), for: .touchDown)


        let statusLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        statusLabel.text = String(posts[indexPath.row].status)

    return cell

}

 func get(_ sender: UIButton){
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let index = sender.tag
    databaseRef.child("location").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in
        guard let firebaseResponse = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else
        {
            print("Snapshot is nil hence no data returned")
            return
        }
        let key = snapshot.key

    let updates: [String: Any] = [
        "/id": key,
        "status": "get it"
    ]
    databaseRef.child("location").child(self.posts[index].key).updateChildValues(updates)


})
    /*
    let imageName = "red.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    index.red.image = image
     */

}
```

[Click this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT0GF.png)
This is display default **green**, When I click one of button it will display **red**.

Comment: do you want that image change when check button clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change in exist cell . as below

**Note it is the sample code you can modify as per your needs**

```
   func get(_ sender: UIButton){
        let cell: TableViewCell? = (sender.superview?.superview as? TableViewCell) // track your cell here
       var indexPath: IndexPath? = yourtbleView?.indexPath(for: cell!)
      cell.red.image = image // change with cell image view
        }
```